# jQuery .load - params in the url - multiparts, multivalue

Tags: jquery, parameters, jquery-load

My params are being extracted form html code and than pasted into `jQuery .load request`.

**Html code:**

```
<a href="#" class="employee">John Doe<span>Lead Web Developer</span></a>
```

**Params extraction from html code, inside `.click`:**

```
        //Create href + params from name + params from title
        var substr = ( $(this).html() ).split('<span>')[0].split(' '); // Get First & Last Name
        var JobTitle = $('span', this).html(); // Get Job Title 

        console.log( JobTitle );  
        // console log will be multivalue (e.g "Lead Web Developer")
```

**jQuery .load request with params**

```
$('.popUp').load("employee.php?FirstName=" + substr[0]+"&LastName=" + substr[1] + "&JobTitle=" + JobTitle, function(){

                // Do Stuff When Done

        });
```

But, the URL I can see in the FireBug looks like that:

`http://host.loc/employee.php?FirstName=John&LastName=Doe&JobTitle=Lead`

---

As you can see, only first word from `var JobTitle` is being used. Why?

**How can I past multivalue param inside the URL?**

Comment: I've used the load function with url contains space for param's value  without any problem. Mabe firebug cannot realize the full url, but it's really sent to server properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should encode the value using [encodeURIComponent()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) to allow spaces in the querystring

```
    var JobTitle = $('span', this).html(); // Get Job Title 
    JobTitle = encodeURIComponent(JobTitle)
    console.log( JobTitle );
```

Answer (score 1):

Encode the params.

Use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/ which would handle it for you.

Example -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var substr = $(this).html().split('<span>')[0].split(' ');
        var JobTitle = $('span', this).html();
        var params = {
            FirstName: substr[0],
            LastName: substr[1],
            JobTitle: JobTitle
        };
        alert($.param(params ));
    });
})
```